# JAXB XJC bindings: renaming @XmlRootElement and @XmlType together

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have the following XML schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="cg" type="cgType"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="cgType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="code" type="upperCaseString" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="action" type="cgAction" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="param" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="automated" type="xsd:boolean" default="false" use="optional"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="cgAction">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="TAKE"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="CLEAR"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="upperCaseString">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="[A-Z]*"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

EDIT: I also have the following global bindings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jaxb:bindings
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        jaxb:version="2.1">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="cg.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
        <jaxb:globalBindings>
            <xjc:simple/>
        </jaxb:globalBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Using XJC to generate classes works as expected, with a class named `Cg` that has both `@XmlType` and `@XmlRootElement` annotations. I want to rename that class to be `CG`, so I changed the binding file to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jaxb:bindings
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        jaxb:version="2.1">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="cg.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="foo.bar.cg"/>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>

        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='cg']">
            <jaxb:class name="CG"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='cgType']">
            <jaxb:class name="CG"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

This causes XJC to complain about a collision in the ObjectFactory class between the two CG classes. If I remove the binding on the `xsd:element`, XJC will now create a `CG` class as expected, however it misses out the `@XmlRootElement` annotation. I've experimented with various combinations of bindings on the `element` and `complexType` but have been unable to simply rename the default generated class.

How can I rename both the `element` and the `complexType` at once?

Answer (score 0):

Both the `element` and `complexType` are their own java classes. Using no binding file you should get the result of 2 class files: `Cg.java` and `CgType.java`. In your bindings your trying to rename both of those to `CG.java` which of course is not possible.

What you are probably looking for is to rename the `complexType` to `CGType` in which case your bindings should read:

```xml
...
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='cg']">
        <jaxb:class name="CG"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='cgType']">
        <jaxb:class name="CGType"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
...
```

Comment: It turns out that by accident I was including `<jaxb:globalBindings>
            <xjc:simple/>
        </jaxb:globalBindings>` in the bindings. This leads to the behaviour I mentioned.